# Windows not loading after 1 RAID-5 disk failed

Tags: windows-7, software-raid, raid-5, intel-rst

I left my PC turned off for just over a week while I was away. When I turned it back on it said my RAID-5 status was degraded and Windows did not want to load.

I replaced the faulty disk and set it to rebuild however it will only re-build once I load into the OS. Windows Startup Repair also does not want to load, it gets the to the PE load screen and the Green bar just keeps going round and round even after leaving it for over an hour.

Any suggestions?

OS: Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit

Raid-5 with Intel Rapid Storage Technology

3 x 1TB disks

UPDATE:

I have tried to load several Windows Boot Disks such as the Dart Disk and a Windows 7 Recovery disk and neither of them get past the "Starting Windows" screen.

Comment: Your using a hardware RAID.  What makes you think you need to be within an OS to rebuild your RAID?  This might be case for using SpinRite but I am not sure it even supports RAID configurations you have to determine if you suffered a soft or hard failure.

Comment: Intel RST is not capable of rebuilding without the OS based software :(